# How to pass float variable from one functions to other function.?

Tags: c, variables, local

I am doing a program in which I have to use a local variable in other function. I am able to do it if the variable data type is int but if it is float then it is not working.

I am using the below code to pass values for int:

```
int func1()
{
    float a = 2.34, b = 3.45, res1;
    int c = 2, d = 3, res2;
    res1 = a * b;
    res2 = c * d;
    return res2;
}

int func2(int res2)
{
    res2 = func1(res2);
    printf("%d", res2);
}
```

so `res2` stores result for int values and `res1` stores result for float values. From the above logic I am able to pass `res2` (which is int) but not able to pass the values of `res1` (which is float). I dont know where I am missing the point. How to do this. Please help, thanks.!

Comment: Is this code working? I really doubt it!! is this not giving any error??

Comment: not it is working for int. :)

Comment: func1() doesnt take any parameters, yet u r calling it with a parameter `func1(res2);`

Comment: What compiler do you use? If this compiles you need to enable (more) warnings.

Comment: func1(res) is the line which recieve the values

Comment: Turn on all your compiler warnings and heed them.

Comment: to only receive the values do `res2 = func1();`.

`res2 = func1(res2);` means you are also sending `res2` to `func1()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of function indicates what types of values it returns

```
// func1 returns values of type int
int func1(void) {
    // return 3.14169; // automagically convert to 3
    // return "pi";    // error: cannot convert "pi" to a value of type int
    return 42;
}
```

If you want a function to return values of floating point type, you need to define them with a floating point type

```
// func3 returns a floating point value of type double
double func3(void) {
    // return 3.14159 // return the value
    // return "pi";   // error: cannot convert "pi" to a value of type double
    return 42;        // converts the int value to the same value in type double
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `float func3()` instead of `double func3()`?

Comment: I think `double` is (almost) always preferred over `float`. I meant any floating point type. But for the example I use the best type available in the absence of more information.

Comment: @pmg you mean to say that I should use double func1, then only it can pass float values to func2

Comment: @AbhinavRawat: if you use `double func1() { /* ... */}` it will never return a value of type `int` ... but pay attention to default conversions!

Comment: @pmg it is not even returning the values for float.